# Shutterstock sends "406 Not Acceptable"

Tags: configuration, blocked-services, server

When I visit a specific webpage with Tor, I received the following error:

> 406 Not Acceptable 
> openresty

Does anybody understand what this means and how I can get around it? I do not receive this error when I use a regular web browser to visit the page.

The page in question is this one: https://submit.shutterstock.com/?language=en

Comment: Some websites block Tor users. It appears Shutterstock is doing so as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to open the [Shutterstock](https://submit.shutterstock.com/?language=en) site and got the same error message. Furthermore I used several different exit relays. All resulting in the same message.

So I assume they block the Tor network. Also the message "406 Not Acceptable" indicates it.

You can try to reach out to them and ask why they're blocking the network. Sometimes companies lift the blocking measures when one discusses with them. Otherwise you won't have much chance to opn the page with Tor.

Comment: I've contacted them and I'll see what they have to say, but I'm not expecting them to change anything. When you say, you won't have much chance, you suggest that there's still something else I could try. Did you have anything in particular in mind?